# Receiving error "invalid identifier" while trying to update a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, query, update, plsql, merge

I'm trying to transform a `Merge query` into an `Update query` for getting better performance but I could not succeed.

Tables structure:

```
create table TEST_FILE_MERGE
(
  customer_num    NUMBER,
  cust_first_name VARCHAR2(180),
  cust_last_name  VARCHAR2(180),
  r_id            NVARCHAR2(1000)
)
create table REQUEST
(
  req_id              NVARCHAR2(1000),
  cust_no             VARCHAR2(50),
  customer_first_name VARCHAR2(50),
  customer_last_name  VARCHAR2(50),
  error_code          NUMBER,
  is_checked          NUMBER(1)
)
```

Here is my Merge query:

```
 MERGE INTO (SELECT * FROM REQUEST WHERE REQ_ID = REQUEST_ID) R
  USING TEST_FILE_MERGE A
  ON (A.CUSTOMER_NUM = R.CUST_NO)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
       SET R.CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME = A.CUST_FIRST_NAME,
           R.CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME  = A.CUST_LAST_NAME,
           R.ERROR_CODE          = 0,
           R.IS_CHECKED          = 1;
```

And Here is my Update Query which is not correct:

```
UPDATE (SELECT A.CUST_FIRST_NAME, A.CUST_LAST_NAME,
          FROM TEST_FILE_MERGE A
         INNER JOIN REQUEST B
            ON A.CUSTOMER_NUM = B.CUST_NO)
   SET B.CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME  = A.CUST_FIRST_NAME,
       B.CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME   = A.CUST_LAST_NAME,
       B.ERROR_CODE           = 0,
       B.IS_CHECKED           = 1;

COMMIT;
```

I receive error `ORA-00904:"B"."IS_CHECKED" invalid identifier` but column `IS_CHECKED`  exists in `REQUEST`  table .

What is wrong with my update query?And how am I suppose to put this part of my merge `SELECT * FROM REQUEST WHERE REQ_ID = REQUEST_ID` into my update statement?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update query doesn't seem complete or it would give another error message , also it helps to make a [mre].

> ```
> create table TEST_FILE_MERGE
> (
>   customer_num    NUMBER,
>   CUST_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(180),
>   CUST_LAST_NAME  VARCHAR2(180),
>   r_id            NVARCHAR2(1000)
>   ,
>   CONSTRAINT cumstom_unique UNIQUE (customer_num)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO TEST_FILE_MERGE VALUES( 123,'perter','foe','1')
> ```

> ```
> create table REQUEST
> (
>   req_id              NVARCHAR2(1000),
>   cust_no             VARCHAR2(50),
>   customer_first_name VARCHAR2(50),
>   customer_last_name  VARCHAR2(50),
>   error_code          NUMBER,
>   "IS_CHECKED"          NUMBER
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO REQUEST VALUES (1,123,'Peter','Foe',0,0)
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE (SELECT A.CUST_FIRST_NAME, A.CUST_LAST_NAME
> ,B.CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME,B.CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME,B.ERROR_CODE,B.IS_CHECKED  
>           FROM TEST_FILE_MERGE A
>          INNER JOIN REQUEST B
>             ON A.CUSTOMER_NUM = B.CUST_NO)
>    SET CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME  = CUST_FIRST_NAME,
>        CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME   = CUST_LAST_NAME,
>        ERROR_CODE           = 0,
>        IS_CHECKED           = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM REQUEST
> ```
>
> ```
> REQ_ID | CUST_NO | CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME | CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME | ERROR_CODE | IS_CHECKED
> :----- | :------ | :------------------ | :----------------- | ---------: | ---------:
> 1      | 123     | perter              | foe                |          0 |          1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=34fba98ea218881f86e337d5e2e405a4)*
*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e25bf9a79ce325543bf5d5f7cc8f9f49)*

Comment: Again I receive "B"."IS_CHECKED" invalid identifier

Comment: please make a [mre] So that i can see if IS_CHECKED exists in `request` your first query seemes to indicate it

Comment: I added the table's structure.

Comment: there is something wroong https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=51001a203d3779e43f3acc765ef4b83a  there is missing REQUEST_ID that looked already strange

Comment: You're right. REQUEST_ID is a parameter. so you can write for example 123 for this parameter . Do this and this error will be solved . Again you see error "B"."IS_CHECKED" invalid identifier

Comment: @Pantea please take a look i made a complete example